# FIlter a list of bootstrap buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a list of bootstrap buttons and also a search box and I want to implement a filter function(preferably in javascript) to filter the number of buttons:

The bootstrap code is here:

https://jsfiddle.net/7zyrdnab/

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="panel">
        <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search">
        <br>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">AA1009</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">AA1010</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">BA1098</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">BB1890</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">C89761</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">CD1667</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">GG7830</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">GF65372</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">BH6537</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">HGB562</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">LK9063</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">CP9871</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">IRON87</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">ACT567</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">MPO760</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">GH5436</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">NBH894</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">GHFDF6</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">US4536</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">MO9854</button>
                     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The filter should work like this:
if AA is typed, only the buttons with the text "aa" should be visible.

The only suggestion i got while searching online was use list.js but I was wondering if there can be a simpler javascript search implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/Shuaso/qhku76bu/

The jquery:

```
var $button = $('.btn');

$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var re = new RegExp($(this).val(), "i"); // case-insensitive
    $button.show().filter(function() {
        return !re.test($(this).text());
    }).hide();   
});
```

Basically you want to run the function each time the user types in the input to filter the elements. You are hiding all buttons that do not match the user input.